# C# how to make image move on Y axis like in slots (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, axis, slots

How can i make image move on Y axis from top to bottom like in slots ?
I have i my WPF this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" Margin="62,97,398,128.6" BorderThickness="2" Name="border" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="obrazekAutomat1" Source="cisla/2.png"/>
                    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I would prefer it in CodeBehind. But i think if you give me XAML i would be able to rewrite it in C#.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as code behind, where `this` is your control

```
this.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

((TranslateTransform) this.RenderTransform).BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation(-100, 100, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));
```

Comment: Cool thats how i wanted it. 
But i have last question:
How can i make a part of the picture disappear when it leaves border ?
Screen:
https://beta.ctrlv.cz/qITU

Comment: @LukasSeidler Wrap the <Border> in a <Canvas>, then set the Cavnas.ClipToBound property to true, that will make the trick

Answer (score 0):

Like every other control, Image Control has a RenderTransform property that you can either set using WPF or C# code, and eventually animate its "Y" property using a double animation.

These links will help you in adding a translate transform and animating it:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/translatetransform-in-wpf/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial